# file/folder synchronization Windows/Fileshares

Tags: windows, network-attached-storage, file-sharing, synchronization

What is the best way to synchronize files/folders - NAS to Windows File Services and Windows File Services to NAS over 200mbps WAN connecton ( time to sync 5 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by "sync". Do you have a distinctive source/destination combination (like ServerA -> ServerB) , or do you need to synchronize changes on both locations?

If you just need to synchronize from A -> B, robocopy would be my first choice. Something like this:

```
robocopy /MIR /R:5 /W:3 /SEC /Z /MT:8 /XJ <source> <destination> /XD thumbs.db
```

If you need more complex (multi source/target synchronizing), you will have to use 3rd party solutions like SyncToy.

Comment: thanks for answering, sync to both locations, after file is changed it should be synced within 5 min to alternate location. NTFS permissions should be the same in both locations.

Comment: 3rd party tool, then.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this program http://alwaysync.com/ to do server migrations. It would like do what you need to do pretty easily. Setup your syncrons and go. Or sync toy and a scheduled task.